# Accent variable, in Sharepoint online theme?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am in the process of creating a custom theme, and I saw an article stating you could add in an accent color with "accent"="#FFF601;"

I added this value to the theme and it shows up on the select a theme screen but I do not see it anywhere on the webpage when the theme is applied.  How do you add an accept color?  I am having a hard time getting two good colors into the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Accent color" is used in **text shading** (in the **Hero Web part**), which is not visible since the “Topic heading text” is empty by default.

I have not found this color in another location though. See the reference here: [Setting the Accent Color of Your Modern Site’s Custom Theme.](https://thechriskent.com/2018/04/20/setting-the-accent-color-of-your-modern-sites-custom-theme/)

[image]

Comment: Boy that stinks.  I am struggling to add a third color without it looking totally bizarre.  My primary color is a bold blue, and I have an accent of yellow or light blue I want to appear sporadically.

Answer (score 0):

So I utilized the theme generated based on my primary colors, then modified the two background colors that were not white or the primary to match colors we use company wide.  I used the accent color but again its a joke a its so minor used.  The plan going forward is to use json formatting and spfx to add in the pops of color that I could not add into the palette branding.